# How to Iterate over two different DataFrame Columns with irregular indexing and better Time complexity?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Assume there are two data frames, df1 and df2 with below data.

```
    df1:
    
    Name     Subject Quarter
    Chinnu   MSCS    Summer
    Vineeth  MBA     Winter
    Chinnu   BSC     Fall

    df2:
    
    Name    SampleName
    Chinnu  Sample 1  
    Vineeth Sample 2
```

I was able to check if df1['Name'] == df2['Name'], then df1['NewName'] = df2['SampleName'] or df1['Name'].to_replace(df2['SampleName']) with the following code.

```
 for i, j in df1.iterrows():
     for x, y in df2.iterrows():
         if(j['Name'] == y['Name']): 
             df.loc[i,'NewName'] = y['SampleName']
```

The above takes more than 5 minutes to execute in VSCode, Python 3.

Note that there are duplicates in df1 but df2 have unique names. Since the indexing is not identical, is there a way to cut short the about code using sort_index or np.where?

I have also tried using the following but seems to be an "non-identical indexing error"

```
df['NewName'] = np.where(df1['Name'] == df2['Name'], df2['SampleName'], df1['Name'])
```

I am new to Programming and apologies if it is a simple question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you post an expected output based on the `DataFrames` `df1` an `df2`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [panda's merge function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

```
df1.merge(df2, on='Name', how='left').rename(columns={'SampleName':'NewName'})
```

Returns

```
    Name Subject  NewName
  Chinnu    MSCS  Sample1
 Vineeth     MBA  Sample2
  Chinnu     BSC  Sample1
```